# How to show values of points on surface plotted with ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

The help for ContourPlot3D starts with this example

```
ContourPlot3D[x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

This returns a Plots of the surface $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$:

[image: Surface].

Now I have a function, and I would like to know how this function behaves on this surface.
For example, take

```
f[x_,y_,z_] := {x^3 - 2 x y + z^2 x - 5 z^2 y^2 - 4 x y z, 
                Sin[10x] + Cos[5y] + Cos[20z]}
```

I was thinking of making a list with some of the point that lie on this surface. Then it is easy to evaluate the function on these points.
The way I would like to generate the list is to click with the mouse on a few points that I think are interesting. Is that possible?

What are the alternatives to using the mouse? There most be some list available with all points that were used to draw this graph. How can I take some point of that list and add them as point to the 3D plot to visualize them?

**Update**

The methods of Szabolcs and Heike work fine on the example $x^3 + y^2 - z^2 =0$.
Now I try to apply the same to

$$
2316 a^{12} c^6+500 a^{11} b c^5+10296 a^{10} b^2 c^4+1624 a^{10} c^5+656 a^9 b^3 c^3- \\
 - 3856 a^9 b c^4+41 a^8 b^4 c^2+808 a^8 b^2 
   c^3+784 a^8 c^4+a^7 b^5 c+24 a^7 b^3 c^2- \\
 - 176 a^7 b c^3+2 a^6 b^4 c+16 a^6 b^2 c^2+32 a^6 c^3 = 0
$$

```
f[a_, b_, c_] := 2 a^6 b^4 c + a^7 b^5 c + 16 a^6 b^2 c^2 + 24 a^7 b^3 c^2 
+ 41 a^8 b^4 c^2 + 32 a^6 c^3 - 176 a^7 b c^3 + 808 a^8 b^2 c^3 
+ 656 a^9 b^3 c^3 + 784 a^8 c^4 - 3856 a^9 b c^4 
+ 10296 a^10 b^2 c^4 + 1624 a^10 c^5 + 500 a^11 b c^5 + 2316 a^12 c^6
pts = {};
```

Substituting this function into Heike's solution does not work. Clicking does not result in points on the surface. 
Also Szabolcs's FindInstance does not work. What goes wrong here?

[image: Surface 2].

Comment: The more general question is how to interact with three dimensional graphics objects using the mouse.  `Tooltip` does work, so there's some support.  But the mouse coordinates can only be retrieved in 2D while this time you want the coordinates in 3D, *on the surface*.  *+1*.

Comment: Why not use built-in visualization capabilities like the MeshFunctions and ColorFunction options?  (MeshFunctions works well to show contours of the first component of `f` while ColorFunction does a better job with its second component, which is rapidly varying; using PlotPoints -> 20 helps.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The location that the mouse is pointing to on a 3D surface can be found by starting with `MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"]`.  This will give you the two points where the line perpendicular to the screen at the mouse pointer intersects the three-dimensional bounding box.

We can calculate the intersection of this line with the surface to find a point.  Here is a simple implementation to track that point dynamically:

`fun` defines the surface:

```
fun[{x_, y_, z_}] := x^3 + y^2 - z^2
```

Let's plot it:

```
plot = ContourPlot3D[
   fun[{x, y, z}] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Now let's try to find the intersection of the mouse pointer with the surface using `FindRoot`.  There might be several intersections, so I specified the box intersection point closer to the viewer as a starting point for `FindRoot` (`t == 0` in the code).  This does not guarantee that the closest (i.e. visible) point will be found, but it makes it more likely.

```
Show[plot,
 Graphics3D[{
   Red,
   Dynamic@Quiet@Check[
      Sphere[#, Scaled[0.01]]& @ Module[{p1, p2, t},
        {p1, p2} = MousePosition[{"Graphics3DBoxIntercepts", Graphics3D}];
        (p2 - p1) t + p1 /. FindRoot[fun[(p2 - p1) t + p1], {t, 0, 0, 1}]
        ],
      {}]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now that we have the point on the surface, you can do with it whatever you want (calculate another functions, etc.)  You can use `EventHandler` to just record clicks instead of tracking values dynamically.

---

To address your other question about how to get a number of points on the surface.  One way is to use `FindInstance`.

```
FindInstance[
 fun[{x, y, z}] == 0 && Thread[-2 < And[x, y, z] < 2, And], {x, y, 
  z}, Reals, 10]
```

This will give you 10 points that are *precisely* on the surface (this uses exact calculations).  Let's show them:

```
Show[plot, Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{x, y, z}, Scaled[0.01]] /. %}]]
```

To get the points generated by `ContourPlot3D`, extract them from the `GraphicsComplex` object is creates.  These coordinates will not be quite as precise as they are meant for visualization only.

```
First@Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[points_, ___] :> points, Infinity]
```

Let's show those points:

```
Graphics3D@Point[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: And you can use `Deploy` to prevent rotating the plot.

Answer (score 11):

This solution is pretty similar to Szabolcs's solution. I've added an `EventHandler` to make it easier to select points in the plot. Here `f[x,y,z]==0` is the equation of the surface, and `pts` contains a list of selected points on this surface. You can add points to the list by right-clicking somewhere on the plot.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^3 + y^2 - z^2;
pts = {};

plot = ContourPlot3D[
   f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   Mesh -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None];
Dynamic@EventHandler[
  Show[plot, Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[#, .05] & /@ pts}]],
  {{"MouseClicked", 2} :> Module[{p, sol, pt},
     p = CurrentValue[{"MousePosition", "Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"}];
     If[p =!= None, 
      sol = Quiet@
        Check[FindRoot[
          f[x, y, z] /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> l p[[1]] + (1 - l) p[[2]]],
          {l, .5, 0, 1}], None];
      If[sol =!= None, 
       AppendTo[pts, l p[[1]] + (1 - l) p[[2]] /. sol]]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If you use `PassEventsDown -> True`, then you can use button-1 clicks while keeping the graphics rotatable (no need for button 2).  Button 2 might still be more comfortable for some people.

Comment: For the `Sphere[]` radius, you could use `Scaled` coordinates to make this independent of the plot range.

Comment: Sorry about a third comment... as you can see, I've been playing with this for a while.  I suggest using `1` as the starting value for `FindRoot` instead of `0.5`.  This will make it much more likely that the solution will be on the side of the surface closer to the viewer.  If you use for example a sphere, many of the points will be on the other (invisible) side of the sphere.  A starting value of `1` brings it to the viewer's side while a starting point of `0` will push it to the opposite side.  You can also localize `l`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Since I restricted the search domain for `FindRoot` to `{0, 1}` I thought it safer to use a starting value somewhere in the middle of the domain than near `x == 1`.

Comment: That is a good point---I just tried `FindRoot[Sin[x], {x, 4, 3.3, 7}]` to make sure.  But we could use `NSolve` instead, which will usually find all roots with good performance *if there's a bound on the solution* (which there is).  Then we can select the largest value of `l`.  Did you know that even `Reduce` can handle these equations in a semi-numerical way, returning `Root` objects which can be evaluated to arbitrary precision?

Comment: @Szabolcs I didn't know that. I always assumed that NSolve could only solve certain types of equations.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about: http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/  I really like this feature.  Though I don't really like the fact that so much advanced functionality is hidden in black box functions which "just work" *if* provided with the right input.  Like using `Boole` to specify regions for `NIntegrate`.  It's not so easy to discover that it will be smart enough to not even sample outside the region specified by `Boole`.

Comment: And also what happens with `NSolve`: if you specify bounds as inequalities, then it'll use a different method internally: `NSolve[Log[2.3 + Sin[x^2 - Log[x]]] == 1 && 0 < x < 4, x]`  Remove the bounds and it'll tell you it can't solve it.  However, as you can see, it won't find all solutions (there are infinitely many in this case)

Comment: @Heike your example works perfect for the surface you use. I tried an other surface: f[a_, b_, c_] := -512 a^6 c (2 - a b + 43 a^2 c)^2 (2 b^4 + a b^5 + 16 b^2 c + 24 a b^3 c + 41 a^2 b^4 c + 32 c^2 - 176 a b c^2 + 808 a^2 b^2 c^2 + 656 a^3 b^3 c^2 + 84 a^2 c^3 - 3856 a^3 b c^3 + 10296 a^4 b^2 c^3 + 1624 a^4 c^4 + 500 a^5 b c^4 + 2316 a^6 c^5) Then many point end up away from the surface. How can that be?