# Cursor function for 3D plots

Tags: plotting

I will illustrate my question with a picture from a matlab plot. Is it possible to do the same thing with *Mathematica* plots in 3D as well?

[image: plot]

The above is from a 3D matlab plot. I can get tooltips showing coordinates of points on the surface. I am searching for the same fror *Mathematica*, but it seems not to work. Has anybody an idea of how to do it with *Mathematica*?

Comment: `Dynamic[a = MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"]]` is a starting point, but some work will be needed to translate the output to `{x,y,z}` values.

Comment: related Q/A: [How can locators be added to points in 3D grid](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5802/125)

Comment: The answer of bbgodfrey seems to be complicated. could anybody translate the output from MousePosition to (x,y,z) for a trivial illustrating example?