# How to make a Locator3D/LocatorSphere?

Tags: graphics3d, gui-construction, customization, locator, user-interface

## **On Making a `LocatorSphere`:**

Okay so I'm trying to realize a `Locator3D-esque` functionality for Mathematica. Something like a `LocatorSphere`, possibly done in a way that the `LocatorVector` can be locked to certain regions/quadrants to ease confusion for the user and prevent egregious errors from occurring.

This will ultimately not be used on a sphere as seen here, so some aspect of customization should be possible (as you see how I have begun to add my own axes) and it needs to output coordinates that can readily be accessed in order to operate other functions, to be used as a locator. For simplicity's sake, it should stay normalized in length. I have something that I think I have taken as far as my skill level can take it. Also, apologies on not having a gif, feel free to add this or a better picture in an edit.

**By modifying this answer:**
[Forcing a locator button to remain on the surface of a sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84238/forcing-a-locator-button-to-remain-on-the-surface-of-a-sphere?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have been able to do the following, which I think is quite a bit towards this goal, but can be taken further and/or optimized and simplified.

```
DynamicModule[{pt}, Manipulate[
  EventHandler[
   Style[
    Graphics3D[{
      {Opacity[0.5],
       First@
        ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {v, 
          0, Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
         MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[1, Automatic], 
         PlotPoints -> ControlActive[Automatic, 50]]},

      {Thick, Arrowheads[Large, Appearance -> "Projected"], 
       Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, Dynamic@pp[[1]]}]},

      {Thick, Arrowheads[Large, Appearance -> "Projected"], 
       Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, {1.5, 0., 0.}}]},

      {Thick, Arrowheads[Large, Appearance -> "Projected"], 
       Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 1.5, 0.}}]},

      {Thick, Arrowheads[Large, Appearance -> "Projected"], 
       Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.5}}]}},

     Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> 1.6,

     Epilog -> 
      Inset[Style[
        "\[Phi]=" <> ToString[#[[2]]] <> ", \[Theta]=" <> 
           ToString[#[[3]]] &@ToSphericalCoordinates[pp[[1]]], 
        FontColor -> 
         Dynamic@If[CurrentValue["ShiftKey"], Black, Gray], 
        18], {Left, Top}, {Left, Top}], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 400},
      RotationAction -> "Clip"], 
    Deployed -> Dynamic@CurrentValue["ShiftKey"]],

   "MouseMoved" :> 
    If[CurrentValue[
      "ShiftKey"], (pp[[First@
            Ordering[Function[pt, (pt - #).(pt - #)] /@ pp, 
             1]]] = #) &@
      Normalize@
       First@MousePosition[
         "Graphics3DBoxIntercepts", {{-1., -1., -1.}, {1., 1., 1.}}]]],
  {{pp, Normalize /@ {{1., 1., 1.}}}, None},
  {nf, None},
  AutorunSequencing -> {2}]]
```

Which gives something like this:

[image: LocatorSphereAttempt]

But there are a few things I cannot make my brain figure out:

## **1. How to have a `Locator` click-and-drag-the-end-of-the-arrow type functionality?**

When you use `Locator` instead of `None` in the last argument for `pp` in manipulate, it ends up creating several errors namely due to the fact that `Locator` uses a 2-D field to deliver its coordinates rather than the implemented 3-D one given by holding shift and moving the mouse around.

## **2. How to make the located coordinates usable in/able to be passed to other functions?**

I genuinely cannot figure out how to access these dynamic variables. Though I can get the proper manipulation of them to occur within the `Manipulate`, it would be great to purposefully leak them to use in other functions, like how a `Locator` is designed to work.

## **3. How to lock the `LocatorVector` to a specific region/quadrant or set of values to prevent the user from making errors based on location choice?**

I think this has something to do with the `"Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"` but I could not get anything meaningful to occur through my experimentation with it.

## **4. How to alter the view angle so that the region the vector starts in is visible to the user without manually rotating the `Graphics3D`?**

This should be an easy one, I think...

## **5. How to improve this implementation further?**

I know this can be immensely improved, and I hope others find this useful, even in its current, rough-and-tumbled format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's something to get you started with a new design.

First we make the function that actually makes a `DynamicModule`. It supports having more than just a sphere as a background, but I haven't really played with that. It also supports the `Dynamic` vocabulary appropriately.

I included a `"PointNormalizer"` in case you want to pass in a `Region` as the background and use `NearestFunction` to compute the nearest point on the region.

I also added in support for automatic `ViewPoint` changes on `"MouseUp"`.

The only annoying thing is that giving a dynamic value for `PassEventsDown` means standard rotations of the scene can be slow...

```
iVectorLocator // Clear
Options[iVectorLocator] =
  {
   "PointNormalizer" -> Normalize,
   "RotateView" -> True
   };
iVectorLocator[
  Dynamic[pt_, {fstart_, f : Except[OptionsPattern[]], fend_}, 
    dops : OptionsPattern[]] |
   Dynamic[pt_, {f : Except[OptionsPattern[]], fend_}, 
    dops : OptionsPattern[]] |
   Dynamic[pt_, f : Except[OptionsPattern[]], dops : OptionsPattern[]] |
   Dynamic[pt_, dops : OptionsPattern[]],
  arrowFunction_: Automatic,
  background_: Automatic,
  ops : OptionsPattern[{iVectorLocator, Graphics3D}]
  ] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {
   active,
   getMousePoint,
   getViewPoint,
   bg,
   ar,
   during,
   pre,
   post,
   vpt,
   rv = OptionValue["RotateView"]
   },
  bg =
   Replace[background, 
    Automatic :>
     {
      {
       Opacity[0.5],
       First@
        ParametricPlot3D[
         {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {v, 0, Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
         MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[1, Automatic], 
         PlotPoints -> ControlActive[Automatic, 50]]
       },
      {
       GrayLevel[.5],
       Dashed,
       {Thick,
        Arrowheads[Large, Appearance -> "Projected"], 
        Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, {1.5, 0., 0.}}]
        }, {Thick, Arrowheads[Large, Appearance -> "Projected"], 
        Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 1.5, 0.}}]},
       {
        Thick,
        Arrowheads[Large, Appearance -> "Projected"], 
        Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.5}}]
        }
       }
      }
    ];
  ar =
   Replace[
    arrowFunction,
    Automatic :>
     Function[
      Null,
      {
       Thick,
       Arrowheads[Large, Appearance -> "Projected"],
       Arrow[{{0., 0., 0.}, Dynamic[#, #2]}]
       },
      HoldFirst
      ]
    ];
  Replace[
   ar[pt, Flatten@{dops}],
   e : With[{aar = ar}, Except[_aar]] :> Set[ar, e]
   ];
  EventHandler[
   Graphics3D[
    {bg, ar},
    FilterRules[
     {
      ops,
      Boxed -> False,
      PlotRange -> 1.6,
      ImageSize -> {Automatic, 400},
      RotationAction -> "Clip",
      If[TrueQ@rv,
       ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vpt],
       Nothing
       ]
      },
     Options[Graphics3D]
     ]
    ],
   {
    "MouseDown" :>
     If[CurrentValue["ShiftKey"],
      pre[pt, getMousePoint[]];
      active = True;
      ],
    "MouseUp" :>
     If[active,
      post[pt, getMousePoint[]];
      If[rv, vpt = getViewPoint[]];
      active = False
      ],
    "MouseDragged" :>
     If[active,
      during[pt, getMousePoint[]]
      ],
    PassEventsDown -> FEPrivate`Not[FrontEnd`CurrentValue["ShiftKey"]]
    }
   ],
  Initialization :> {
    If[! ValueQ[pt], pt = Normalize[{1., 1., 1.}]],
    If[rv, vpt = getViewPoint[], vpt = Automatic],
    during = Replace[{f}, {} | {Automatic} -> {Set}][[1]],
    pre = Replace[{fstart}, {} | {Automatic} -> {during}][[1]],
    post = Replace[{fend}, {} | {Automatic} -> {during}][[1]],
    With[{norm = OptionValue["PointNormalizer"]},
     getMousePoint[] :=
      norm@First@
        MousePosition[
         "Graphics3DBoxIntercepts", {{-1., -1., -1.}, {1., 1., 1.}}]
     ],
    getViewPoint[] :=
     pt*2
    }
  ]
```

Now we'll turn that into a `Format`ted form of a different object. This is how most FE things are built.

```
Options[VectorLocator] =
  {
   Appearance -> Automatic
   };
Format[
  v :
   VectorLocator[
    d : (
      Dynamic[pt_, {fstart_, f : Except[OptionsPattern[]], fend_}, 
        dops : OptionsPattern[]] |
       Dynamic[pt_, {f : Except[OptionsPattern[]], fend_}, 
        dops : OptionsPattern[]] |
       Dynamic[pt_, f : Except[OptionsPattern[]], dops : OptionsPattern[]] |
       Dynamic[pt_, dops : OptionsPattern[]]
      ),
    background : Except[OptionsPattern[]] : Automatic,
    ops : OptionsPattern[{VectorLocator, Graphics3D, iVectorLocator}]
    ],
  StandardForm
  ] :=
 Interpretation[
  iVectorLocator[d, 
   OptionValue[{VectorLocator, Graphics3D, iVectorLocator}, {ops}, 
    Appearance], 
   background,
   FilterRules[
    {ops},
    Join[Options[iVectorLocator], Options[Graphics3D]]
    ]
   ],
  v
  ]
```

Now you can use it in the normal way like:

```
VectorLocator[Dynamic[vec], Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image]

or if you want it to spit out the end position:

```
VectorLocator[Dynamic[vec, {Automatic, Echo[#] &}], Background -> LightBlue]
```

or if you want a different shape as the background:

```
VectorLocator[Dynamic[pt], 
 GeometricTransformation[Sphere[], ScalingTransform[{1, .5, .5}]],
 Axes -> True,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}
 ]
```

[image]

And as you might guess from the fact that we pass a `Dynamic` as the first argument, if two of these things share the same variable and update to one will affect the other, which can be interesting to watch.

I think I actually hit the first four of your requests in doing this, even if by accident, too.

Comment: Bravo! Stupendo! Bellissimo! This is a learning experience to say the least, I will leave this open for a good day or so before I lock in the check-a-doodle-doo, but I think this is a clearly nailed answer. One thing, when you put the `"RotateView"` to false, it throws an error before you interact with it, after this it is good to go. Probably some error on my part, but it is the only issue and a rather small insignificant one at-that. This is amazing!

Comment: @CATrevillian I might have forgotten to put the updated code on there. Give it another go.

Comment: Ah, funny funny, it only occurs when I do not delete the prior output, which makes sense. That would be the only way for `Viewpoint Automatic is not a triple of numbers or a recognized symbolic form.` to be outputted as an error, because the previously defined `Dynamic` is picking up the newly defined value of `vpt` before the whole construct is updated upon user interaction. Quite curious, but altogether, I think, user error on my part :D

Comment: @CATrevillian not user error, I'd say. Just kinda surprising.

Comment: It’s definitely a side-effect of how `Graphics3D` objects can end up saving the orientation between modifications and how changes to how a `Manipulate` is defined (on a `Graphics3D`?) will update the previously evaluated output without re-evaluation. Iirc there’s either some way to purposefully disable or enable this effect, but it is only one of those directions & not both that can be taken. In the end, I agree, it is strange & surprising! I’m sure some keen abuse/advantage of this can can be taken, but I’ve got no clue what one could do knowing how to do that. Very nice work, b3.

Comment: Hey b3, can you clarify for me what exactly is the purpose of the `Dynamic[#,#2]` part of the `ar=`? Because it displays pink, I am not confident about how exactly it is functioning without a `&` to "seal it up" into a pure function. Additionally, for the manipulation of the vector itself, should we be able to add some `Dynamic[If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], ar ] ]` type of extra requirement so that you can be dragging the tip of the vector to manipulate it?

Comment: @CATrevillian the `Dynamic[#,#2]` _is_ wrapped up in a `Function` head to make it a pure function. The FE just is bad at highlighting. Its purpose is to capture the passed variable and dynamic options. You can certainly add a `Dynamic[...]` there, but you can also pass a different arrow generating function via the `Appearance` option. E.g. `VectorLocator[..., Appearance->Function[Null, Point[Dynamic[#, #2]], HoldFirst]]`