# Rotating 3D graphics inside Show separately by clicking and dragging

Tags: graphics3d, rotation

Is there a way how to rotate by clicking and dragging just one of the 3D graphics inside Show?

For example rotating the cube without rotating the tetrahedron in this code:

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Cube[]}, Boxed -> False], 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Tetrahedron[]}, Boxed -> False]]
```

I know how to do it by code, I just want to know whether there exist some parameter for `Graphics3D` that disables rotating by mouse, something like `RotationDisable->True`. And then one graphics would have `RotationDisable->True` and the other `RotationDisable->False`.

If there is no way how to do it for `Show` then what would be the easiest way to achieve rotating of cube by mouse while tetrahedron stays stationary?

Comment: `Manipulate` or `DynamicModule` seems the only way right now.

Comment: this may be useful: [How can locators be added to the points on a 3D grid?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6061/125)

Comment: @cvgmt, @kglr: I did it with `DynamicModule` but it is not as good as it would be with mouse dragging straight on the graphics itself. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
angularSlider[Dynamic[angle_]] := 
 DynamicModule[{p = {1, 0}, angleCalc}, 
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[p, (angleCalc @@ Normalize /@ {#, p}) &], 
   Graphics[{Circle[], Arrowheads[0.15], Arrow[Dynamic[{{0, 0}, p}]]},
     ImageSize -> Tiny], Appearance -> None], 
  Initialization :> (angle = 0; 
    angleCalc[newp_, 
      oldp_] := (angle = 
       angle + ArcCos[newp.oldp] Sign[Cross[newp].(newp - oldp)]; 
      p = {Cos[angle], Sin[angle]}))]
```

Then using this code:

```
angularSlider[Dynamic[\[Theta]]]
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.7], Cube[1/2], 
  GeometricTransformation[Tetrahedron[], 
   RotationMatrix[Dynamic[\[Theta]], {0, 1, 1}]]}, Boxed -> False, 
 SphericalRegion -> True, ViewVector -> {{3, 3, 3}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
 RotationAction -> "Clip", PlotRange -> 2]
```

[image]

You can rotate whole graphics with mouse as usually, plus you can rotate only tetrahedron using the mouse on the arrow inside circle.

Lots of code for a trivial thing to do... I think it should be implemented in Mathematica naturally to rotate graphics inside `Show` separately, because doing this by code is very cumbersome and still not as good as if rotated by mouse dragging straight on the graphics itself.

[image]