# How to realize Locator3D effect?

Tags: dynamic

I want to use the locator in MMA to reproduce the following animation:

[image]

But MMA's function `Locator` doesn't support 3D coordinates. What can I do to reproduce this animation?

Comment: possible duplicate: [How can locators be added to the points on a 3D grid?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5802/125)

Answer (score -1):

The following code is written by [chyanog](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2090/chyanog):

```
DynamicModule[{x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
  pos, pos1}, 
 EventHandler[
  Graphics3D[{EventHandler[
     Dynamic@{{Riffle[{Red, Green}, 
         Tooltip[Sphere[#, 0.075], #] & /@ pts]}, 
       Line[pts], {{x0, y0, z0}, {x1, y1, z1}} = pts; 
       InfinitePlane[
        pts[[1]], {{0, z0 - z1, y1 - y0}, {z0 - z1, 0, 
          x1 - x0}}]}, {"MouseDown" :> (pos = 
         Nearest[pts, MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"]][[1, 
           1]];
        pos1 = FirstPosition[pts, pos]), 
      "MouseDragged" :> (pts[[pos1]] = (#[[2]] + 
             Projection[
              pos - #[[2]], #[[1]] - #[[2]]]) &@(MousePosition[
            "Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"]))}]}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   PlotRange -> 
    Table[{-1, 2}, 3]], {{"MouseClicked", 
     2} :> (First@MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"])}]]
```

Comment: This code is buggy and, IMO, doesn't answer the question. Also, I think you should supply a link to the code and not to chyanog's user profile.