# Controlling point in graphics 3D with locator

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, scripting

I want to control a point in 3D graph by dragging it with the mouse
lets say this is my code and I want to add some functionality like the way locator works in 2d graphics

```
  Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[pt]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}
    }, Axes -> True], {{pt, {1, 1, 1}}, {-5, -5, -5}, {5, 5, 5},**Locator**}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can locators be added to the points on a 3D grid?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-can-locators-be-added-to-the-points-on-a-3d-grid)

Comment: You might be interested in [`ResourceFunction["Locator3D"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Locator3D/) - it is intended to be a drop-in replacement for `Locator` in 3D. (Apart from the fact that you can't use it as control type for `Manipilate`) - I'll add a more concrete answer once I'm back at my PC

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`ResourceFunction["Locator3D"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Locator3D/) as follows:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  {Black, PointSize[0.02], ResourceFunction["Locator3D"][Dynamic@pt]},
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
  Axes -> True
  ],
 {{pt, {1, 1, 1}}, None}
 ]
```

[image]

Note how I set the control type of `pt` to `None`, and added the locator to the graphics myself. This is currently necessary, as `Manipulate` doesn't support custom "fancy" controls that merge with the content (effectively what is done for `Locator`). If you want to impose limits on the location of the locator, use the two-argument form of `Dynamic` (examples for how this works can also be seen in the documentation for `Locator`):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  {Black, PointSize[0.02],
   ResourceFunction["Locator3D"][
    Dynamic[pt, (pt = Clip[#, {-5, 5}]& /@ #)&]]
   },
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
  Axes -> True
  ],
 {{pt, {1, 1, 1}}, None}
 ]
```

This resets the position to the allowed region before actually assigning it to `pt`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's helpful, but the function PointSize[#] is not effective either the color can not be changed in this form,
 do you know how to change the point size or the color? because this {Black, Point Size[0.02] ...} is not effective

Comment: @TtTt If you are talking about changing the appearance of the sphere: similarly to the 2D locator, the appearance can be controlled using the second argument of `Locator3D` (see also the examples in the "Scope" section of the documentation). For reference, the default is something like `{Black, Sphere[{0,0,0}, Scaled[0.05]]}`. Note that you might also need to change the size of the handles (the colored arrows), this can be done using the `ImageSize` option (agian, see the examples in the documentation)

Comment: @TtTt FYI, the fixed version of the function is now available from the repository, so `ResourceFunction["Locator3D"]` is all you need (you might need to update your local version using `ResourceUpdate@ResourceFunction["Locator3D"]`)

Answer (score 13):

Well, I wrote an [interactive Variable Calculus book](https://tecdigital.tec.ac.cr/servicios/revistamatematica/Libros/) and, as I don't know a "3D locator", I used mouse events to select and drag points. I learned the code from several posts.  Here I share tow basic examples

First one you can see in  [here](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/author.html?author=Walter%20Mora%20Flores). Second one follow

[image]

The code is

```
Manipulate[Grid[{
(*Titulos*)
{Style["Puntos en 3D", Bold, 10,RGBColor[0.12, 0, 0.5]]},
{
(*------------------------------------------    3D      --------------------*)
DynamicModule[{pts={{2,0,2},{0,2,1}},index=0,pos0,pos1,mypr={{-2,4},{-2,4},{-2,4}},AV1Cap1Obj},
(*Objetos*)
AV1Cap1Obj[var_]:=If[var==1,{Thickness[0.0001],Arrowheads[0.00], Arrow[ {{0,0,0},{0,0,0}} ]  },
If[var==2,{PointSize[0.03], Point[Dynamic@pts[[2]]],FaceForm[],EdgeForm[], Cuboid[Dynamic[pts[[2]]-{0.5,0.5,0.5}]]   } ]   ];
(*       *)
EventHandler[
Graphics3D[{
AV0Cap1ejes,
 (*----------   Parte dinámica --------------*)
Dynamic[{Text[,1.1pts[[2]],{0,-1}],
Dashed, Thick, RGBColor[0, 0.3, 0], Gray,
Line[{{pts[[2,1]],0,0},{pts[[2,1]],pts[[2,2]],0},{0,pts[[2,2]],0}}],Line[{{pts[[2,1]],pts[[2,2]],0},pts[[2]],{0,0,pts[[2,3]]}}],
Text[Style[NumberForm[Round[pts[[2,1]],0.1],2],Bold,10],{pts[[2,1]],-0.4,0}],
Text[Style[NumberForm[Round[pts[[2,2]],0.1],2],Bold,10],{-0.4,pts[[2,2]],0}],Text[Style[NumberForm[Round[pts[[2,3]],0.1],2],Bold,10],{0,-0.4,pts[[2,3]]}]
                    }],
MouseAppearance[EventHandler[ (*Función: Aplica # a {1,2,...}*)
Mouseover[ 
{ (*expr base, mouse fuera*)
Dynamic[If[index===#,Red,RGBColor[0, 0.34, 0]]],AV1Cap1Obj[#]
},
{(* mouse over*)
Dynamic[If[index===0||index===#,Red,RGBColor[0, 0.34, 0]]],AV1Cap1Obj[#]
}
](*MouseOver*),
{"MouseDown":>(index=#;pos0=pts[[index]]) (*Selecciona: pos0 = posición actual*)
},
PassEventsUp->True]&/@Range[Length[pts]](*EventHandler local, #=1,2,....*),"Arrow"]
} (*Opciones Graphics3D*)
,PlotRange->mypr,ImageSize->350, ViewPoint->{1,1, 0.6}, Boxed->False,ImagePadding->None,SphericalRegion->True](*Graphics3D*)

,{ (*Si arrastra...*)
"MouseDragged":>If[index>0,((pos1=#[[2]]+Projection[pos0-#[[2]],#[[1]]-#[[2]]])&@MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"]);
pts[[index]]=pos1
], (*Clip puntos*)
"MouseUp":>(pts[[All,3]]=Clip[pts[[All,3]],{-1.8,2.8}];pts[[All,2]]=Clip[pts[[All,2]],{-1.8,2.8}];pts[[All,1]]=Clip[pts[[All,1]],{-1.8,2.8}];
index=0)
},
(*Pass the events to LocatorPane by setting PassEventsDown\[Rule]True in the deepest event handlers*)
PassEventsDown->True](*EventHandler Global*)
](*DynamicModule*)
}}, Alignment->Top], (*Grid*)
(*-------Manipulate------*)
ContentSize ->Automatic,
ControlPlacement->Top,
AppearanceElements->None,
Alignment->{Top},
SaveDefinitions->True,
SynchronousInitialization->False,
Initialization:>{ violeta=RGBColor[0.12, 0, 0.5];
Ejes3DTxy[xmin_,xmax_,ymin_,ymax_,zmin_,zmax_]:={
Black,Arrowheads[Medium],
Arrow[Tube[{{xmin,0,0.01},{0,0,0.01},{xmax,0,0.01}},0.007]],
Arrow[Tube[{{0,ymin+0.01,0.01},{0,0,0.01},{0,ymax+0.01,0.01}},0.007]],
Arrow[Tube[{{0.01,0.01,zmin+0.01},{0.01,0.01,0.01},{0,0,zmax+0.01}},0.007]],
Gray,
Table[Line[{{IntegerPart[xmin],i,0},{IntegerPart[xmax],i,0}}],{i,IntegerPart[ymin],IntegerPart[ymax],1}],Table[Line[{{i,IntegerPart[ymin],0},{i,IntegerPart[ymax],0}}],{i,IntegerPart[xmin],IntegerPart[xmax],1}],
};
AV0Cap1ejes=Ejes3DTxy[-1,3,-1,3,0,3];
wNformat[var_]:=Style[NumberForm[Round[ var ,0.1],3],Bold,12,RGBColor[0.23, 0, 0.70]]}]
```